# Highcharts Information bubbles at bottom of chart - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have built a chart and I am looking to add information bubbles (like the image below) to the bottom of the chart, is there anything in [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) that I could use to do this?

[image]

Comment: You may want to checkout [d3 (data driven documents)](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery), it's what github uses to render [their graphs](https://github.com/blog/1093-introducing-the-new-github-graphs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a scatter plot series to add dots at specific points.  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSD6G/) and code:

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis : {
            min:0
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            name: 'Temperature'
        }, {
            type: 'scatter',
            data: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
            name: 'Rainfall'
        }]
    });
});​
```

Edit:

You can set showInLegend to false to hide the scatter series from the legend, and you could add a tooltip function to display whatever info you want.